# Bootstrap 5 Mixin Not Changing Background Color For Button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Hi I try to change the background become blue, and the text color become white for my button in Bootstrap 5 using Mixin

When I refresh the browser, the button does not change as expected and when I check to inspect the element, their text is in the line where my mixin becomes unused

I think the color does not change because my mixin cant overwrite the background color and text color from class .btn

[image]

[image: Property of .btn class]

```
.btn-blue-700-rounded {

@include button-variant($white, $blue-700, $blue-700);
border-radius: 100px;}
```